# Why aren’t (type theory based) automated theorem provers efficient?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, automated-theorem-proving

Note: my main experience with theorem provers is with Type theory based proof-assistant, rather than an actual automated theorem prover.

It is obvious why *naive* automated theorem proving is inefficient: just doing an uninformed search through proof-space (e.g. with breadth first search) runs into the problem that the number of nodes in the proof tree increases exponentially with the number of steps.

**What I am wondering is**: Why haven’t we yet been able to create heuristics that guide an informed search to the point that automated theorem provers beat human mathematicians in proving theorems across the board? **What makes it difficult to formulate such heuristics?**